# java.lang.ClassCastException when using ListView inside LinearLAyout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have used an answer on stackoverflow to edit the default android navigation drawer.

My problem is when running the project I get this error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView
       at uk.co.mrgyro.cropcirclelocatorandroid.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:97)
```

Looking at other answers this seams to be caused by using a reserved word, however as far as I am aware I am not using one.

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

private ImageView mDrawerImage;
private TextView mDrawerText;

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // need site names for list
    String[] siteNames = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.section_titles);


    // inflate the parent view (the entire layout)
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    // now grab the separate child views from inside it
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_listView);
    mDrawerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_image);
    mDrawerText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_text);

    // configure the Views
    mDrawerText.setText("Give it a name/title");
    //mDrawerImage.setImageURI(...);    // set your ImageView however you want, I just gave it one in XML
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, siteNames));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    // and return the inflated view up the stack
    return view;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the webviews content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
      //  inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- the root view is now a LinearLayout, all other Views are children of this -->
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#cccc"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/listview2">

<!-- a separate section to go above the list -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- your image, you can set it later (see NavDrawerFrag) -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"/>

    <!-- a bit of test or a title to go with it -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Default text"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- some divider thing -->
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="#000000"/>

<!-- your ListView is now a child View -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possibly an issue that can be solved by cleaning / re-building the project. Also, what is line 97?

Comment: I have unfortunately tried a project clean. Line 97 is the "Public View onCreateView...

Comment: @njzk2 this won't be solved cleaning or rebuilding project.

Comment: just try renaming <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listview" to something else .Just a try

Comment: @Karthika PB, you should put that in an answer and you get a tick, it worked and has exposed another error in my code further down the line.

Comment: @Lister I did it see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of the id in the following layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

change like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

You are using listview as id for Linear Layout.Change this to something else.Because listview is a keyword in android.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` and `LinearLayout` are different elements !! If you want to use a list view, just add the `<ListView .... />` element in your xml, instead of the `<LinearLayout>` with id  `listview`